# Build a hosted Call Center Solution/ IVR by extending FreePbx/Elastix

Tags: php, asterisk, freepbx, elastix

I m currently using Elastix as IPPBX solution. Would like to know the possibility to extend it as a hosted solution where few clients can be added to the application. Was planning to have a web application which needs to be developed so that the clients can have their logins ( php application instead of elastix login) and they can add extensions, users , DIDs, Upload IVR, call reports etc from there.

Bit confused on how would I accomplish this. Have come across PHP AGI which can be used , but in that case , would I require to create a complete IPPBX solution from scratch (like Elastix ) ?. I'm looking to have elastix or FreePBX done with all the needed configuration, but a separate small web application to deal with only requirements I had mentioned above.Does Freepbx/Elastix provide APIs ? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Develop such solution from sratch will cost you less. Do multitenant on freepbx will require full rewrite of most modules.

There is [virtualpbx by Igor Okunev](http://virtual-pbx.ru/en/prices.html) solution which offer free(upto 10 concurrent calls, after that $1500 cost) multitenant web

No other well-known multitenant web exists as far as i know.

As other option you can start virtualization server(openvz or kvm) and setup a number of freepbx which work in virtual environment for each client.

Comment: Sorry? You can't implement pbx on aws. You can do on EC2. There are very few difference between usual VPS and EC2, so i not understand you question. Just need implement it, that will require time&money, alot of. Thats all. No rocket science